# Efficient Partitioning of Pandas DataFrame rows between sandwiched indicator variables

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Suppose I have a pandas df with an indicator row that sandwiches a period. Ex.

```
In [9]: pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.arange(1,11),'indicator':[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]})
Out[9]: 
   col1  indicator
0     1          0
1     2          1
2     3          0
3     4          0
4     5          0
5     6          1
6     7          0
7     8          0
8     9          1
9    10          1
```

What I want to do, is to use groupby to select the partitions separated by the indicators.

ex.

Group 1

```
col1  indicator
0     1          0
1     2          1
```

Group 2

```
2     3          0
3     4          0
4     5          0
5     6          1
```

Group 3

```
6     7          0
7     8          0
8     9          1
```

Group 4

```
9    10          1
```

The naive solution will be to just take the indicator column out as a list, run a for-loop through it, and just label each part. But suppose the dataset is really big, and you want to avoid the for-loop. Is there something more clever that can be done here, to separate out the different groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign another column as a `cumsum` of `indicator`, then apply `groupby`, this should do the trick:

```
# reverse the order as you have indicator at end of group, then reverse back
df['grouped'] = df['indicator'].loc[::-1].cumsum().loc[::-1]

for g in df.groupby('grouped', sort=False):
    print g
(4,    col1  indicator  grouped
0     1          0        4
1     2          1        4)
(3,    col1  indicator  grouped
2     3          0        3
3     4          0        3
4     5          0        3
5     6          1        3)
(2,    col1  indicator  grouped
6     7          0        2
7     8          0        2
8     9          1        2)
(1,    col1  indicator  grouped
9    10          1        1)
```